# How do you dynamically mask data that saved as json via Azure?

Tags: sql, azure, dynamic, masking, data-masking

I'm trying to mask sensitive data via an Azure SQL database.
The data is saved as normal text and one column as XML and another saved as json.
I've tried adding rules to the database but when I open SSMS and run a select statement it does not apply to any of the data in the columns (normal text, xml or json saved data)

There's no user excluded to see unmasked data.
Just want to understand why the data is not masked when I perform a select on SSMS.

My rules look like the below:

XML Rule

[image: XML Rule]

JSON Rule:

[image: Json Rule]

Text Rule:

[image: Text rule]

My SQL statment:

SELECT TOP (1000)  * from database_Name

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/dynamic-data-masking-configure-portal?view=azuresql) it says,

> The identities in Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) or SQL are included in the masking process and should have access to the unmasked sensitive data.

Maybe you are accessing data as `SQL admin` or `Azure AD user` because of that you can see sensitive data.

By hiding important information from unwanted users at multiple layers of the database, you may prevent access and gain control. You may give or remove UNMASK permission to a user.

The code taken from [Microsoft-documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/dynamic-data-masking-overview?view=azuresql#granular-permission-example) it says,

Give UNMASK permission to user

```sql
GRANT UNMASK ON Data.Membership TO USER;
```

To Query the data under the context of user

```sql
EXECUTE AS USER='USER';
```

To revoke UNMASK permissions

```sql
REVOKE UNMASK ON Data.Membership FROM USER;
```

***Data after granting permission to user***

[image]

***Data after removing permission from user***

[image]

***Taken Reference from:***

[SQL Database dynamic data masking with the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/dynamic-data-masking-configure-portal?view=azuresql)

[Granting and Revoking the Permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/dynamic-data-masking-overview?view=azuresql#granular-permission-example)

Comment: I have checked with different accounts and that didn't seem to be the problem. 
I left the rules for over a weekend and magically it applied to the database.
I am guessing that there is some time span that needs to take place before it's implemented across all the tables